# AngularJS 1.2, Bootstrap 3.0 panel collapse not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest Anugular JS 1.2 and bootstrap 3.0. The accordion has been changed to a panel. I'm unable to make the panel work with the latest Angular JS. Here is the plunker I created. Any help is much appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BZa5CUVdltFk3k8XrxdO?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I ran the plunker with the JS console opened, and saw this message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Maybe that's what's wrong.

Comment: That is part of the Angular.js file not something I wrote. Do you have an example on how to get the panel to work with the latest Angular JS and latest Bootstrap?

Comment: I just moved the "require" for jQuery up a few lines, to precede Bootstrap, and now the plunker seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing the order in which the js is included within my application outside of plunker and I still can't get it to work correctly. It was working perfectly till I upgraded to Angular JS 1.2

Comment: The code you have has nothing to do with the angular js file. Post some angular code. That would be helpful